# Python multiprocessing and MPI multi-node

Tags: python, multiprocessing, mpi, communication

Here is my problem. I'm working on an existing python multiprocessing code (running on a single node) and the objective is to do a multi-node execution of this code using MPI for Python (mpi4py).

The MPI communications between 2 nodes are only done by the main thread of each MPI Process(the thread who call MPI.Init(), you can know which one did it by calling the MPI.Is_thread_main() function) but unfortunately don't work.

In fact, the MPI Communication doesn't work AFTER the python processes start.

To explain the problem, I re-write a short code having exactly the same problem.

```
import os
import psutil
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import Queue
import time

from mpi4py import rc
rc.initialize = False # if = True, The Init is done when "from mpi4py import MPI" is called
rc.thread_level = 'funneled'

from mpi4py import MPI


def infiniteloop(arg):
    while True:
        print(arg)
        time.sleep(1)
        # Check if the worker think it's the thread who called MPI.Init()
        print("Worker is Main Thread %s" %(MPI.Is_thread_main()))
        print("Rank %d on %s, Process PID for worker = %d" %(MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank(),MPI.Get_processor_name(),os.getpid()))



if __name__ == '__main__':

    MPI.Init()
    # In the code I'm working on, MPI.Init() has to be done before the miltiprocess initialization

    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=infiniteloop, args=('RunningWorker',))
    proc.start()
    print("MultiProcess Stared")


    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    rank = comm.Get_rank()
    size_mpi = comm.Get_size()

    while True:
        print("Running Main Thread")
        print("Main Thread is Main Thread %s" %( MPI.Is_thread_main()))
        print("Rank %d on %s, Process PID for main = %s" %(MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank(),MPI.Get_processor_name(),os.getpid()))
        print("Rank %d on %s, rc.thread_level = %s" %((MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank(),MPI.Get_processor_name(), rc.thread_level)))
        time.sleep(1)

        # Start MPI Communication, It is just an example of 2D array communication which I know it works
        print("Start MPI Transfert")
        #*************** Multiple SEND AND RECEIVE for 2D Array fill randomly
        SumPsfmean = None
        TransPsfmean = None
        TABSIZE = 100
        # Create 100x100 array with random np.float64 values
        # (Because it's really close from the case I'm intersting for)
        # Row per row communication
        if rank == 0:
            psfmean = np.random.rand(TABSIZE,TABSIZE)
            print(psfmean.dtype)
        else:
            psfmean = np.random.rand(TABSIZE,TABSIZE)

        psfmean_shape = psfmean.shape

        if rank == 0:
            SumPsfmean = np.array(range(psfmean.size*(size_mpi-1)), dtype = np.float64)
            SumPsfmean.shape = (size_mpi-1, psfmean_shape[0], psfmean_shape[1])
            TransPsfmean = np.array(range(psfmean[0].size), dtype = np.float64)

        for i in range(psfmean_shape[1]):
            print("Rank %d : Send&Receive nb %d" %(rank, I))
            if rank == 0:
                comm.Recv(TransPsfmean, source=1, tag=i)
            elif rank ==1:
                comm.Send(psfmean[i], dest=0, tag=i)
            print"End Send&Receive %d" %i
            if rank == 0:
                for k in range(size_mpi):
                    if k != 0:
                        SumPsfmean[k-1][i] = TransPsfmean


    proc.join()
```

In this example, only 2 MPI process are created on 2 different nodes.
So, after init the MPI, the main function will create and start a python process then will start a communication between the 2 MPI process. The MPI_rank_1 will send row per row the information of a 2D array (100 rows) and the MPI_rank_0 will wait to receive this information.

The Result is :

```
[0] MultiProcess Stared
[0] Running Main Thread
[0] Main Thread is Main Thread  : True
[0] Rank 0 on genji271, Process PID for main = 227040
[0] Rank 0 on genji271, rc.thread_level = funneled
[1] MultiProcess Stared
[1] Running Main Thread
[1] Main Thread is Main Thread  : True
[1] Rank 1 on genji272, Process PID for main = 211028
[1] Rank 1 on genji272, rc.thread_level = funneled
[0] RunningWorker[0]
[1] RunningWorker
[0] Start MPI Transfert
[0] float64
[1] Start MPI Transfert
[1] Rank 1 : Send&Receive nb 0
[1] End Send&Receive 0
[1] Rank 1 : Send&Receive nb 1
[1] End Send&Receive 1
[1] Rank 1 : Send&Receive nb 2
[1] End Send&Receive 2
[1] Rank 1 : Send&Receive nb 3
[1] End Send&Receive 3
[1] Rank 1 : Send&Receive nb 4
[1] End Send&Receive 4
[1] Rank 1 : Send&Receive nb 5
[1] End Send&Receive 5[1]
[1] Rank 1 : Send&Receive nb 6[1]
[1] End Send&Receive 6
[1] Rank 1 : Send&Receive nb 7
[1] End Send&Receive 7[1]
[1] Rank 1 : Send&Receive nb 8
[1] End Send&Receive 8
[1] Rank 1 : Send&Receive nb 9
[1] End Send&Receive 9
[1] Rank 1 : Send&Receive nb 10
[1] End Send&Receive 10
[1] Rank 1 : Send&Receive nb 11
[1] End Send&Receive 11
[1] Rank 1 : Send&Receive nb 12
[1] End Send&Receive 12
[1] Rank 1 : Send&Receive nb 13
[1] End Send&Receive 13
[1] Rank 1 : Send&Receive nb 14[1]
[1] End Send&Receive 14
[1] Rank 1 : Send&Receive nb 15
[0] Rank 0 : Send&Receive nb 0
[0] Worker is Main Thread : True
[0] Rank 0 on genji271, Process PID for worker = 227046
[0] RunningWorker
[1] Worker is Main Thread : True
[1] Rank 1 on genji272, Process PID for worker = 211033
[1] RunningWorker
[0] Worker is Main Thread : True
[0] Rank 0 on genji271, Process PID for worker = 227046
[0] RunningWorker
[1] Worker is Main Thread : True
[1] Rank 1 on genji272, Process PID for worker = 211033
[1] RunningWorker
[0] Worker is Main Thread : True
[0] Rank 0 on genji271, Process PID for worker = 227046
...
```

As you see, the worker and the main thread both think to be the thread who called MPI.Init(). 
Moreover, the MPI Communication stops between the 2 MPI process (it works perfectly without python process or when MPI.Init is done after the creation of the process !!). Actually, The MPI_rank_0 who's supposed to receive the rows is stuck in the first iteration and never receives this first row.

I (think) understand that a python process is a kind of clone of the main thread (or at least share/copy the memory of the main thread when the process is created). So is it possible that MPI doesn't see the difference between the main thread and its clone (Event if they have a different PID !!). Or maybe am I doing something wrong?

Is anyone could help me? I'd really appreciate it and could share you with more information about my problem.

Comment: from the doc, it seems `multiprocessing` does start a new process (vs a new thread) and that likely confuses `Is_thread_main()`. That being said, bad things can happen if you fork a new process **after** `MPI_Init()` so you might want **not** to do that in the first place.